# Как составить запрос с несколькими условиями используя CDbCriteria?

Tags: php, yii, activerecord

Пользовался этой инструкцией для создания постраничной разбивки http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/postranichnaja-razbivka-v-yii

Мой код:

```
// Постраничная выборка всех рекламных новостей
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->condition='is_reklama=:isRekl';
    $criteria->params=array(':isRekl'=>1);
    $count=Article::model()->count($criteria);

    $pagination=new CPagination($count);
    $pagination->pageSize=3;
    $pagination->applyLimit($criteria);

    $articles = Article::model()->findAll($criteria);
```

У меня запрос составлен с условием `is_reklama=:isRekl`.
Мне нужно в выборку добавить еще одно условие. Для этого я решил заменить метод `findAll()` на `findAllByAttributes()`.
Только я не могу понять как можно в `findAllByAttributes()` прередать несколько условий запроса используя `CDbCriteria`? Если не использовать `CDbCriteria`, то все ясно, просто параметром передаю массив ключей и значений. А для пагинации нужнен запрос именно с `CDbCriteria`. Заранее благодарю)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findAllByAttributes` Не нужен, если используется CDBCriteria.
Используйте [CDbCriteria->addCondition](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addCondition-detail). 
`$criteria->params=array(':isRekl'=>1);` Можно дополнять элементами массива.
Пример дополнительного условия:

```
$criteria->addCondition('is_super_puper_relama > :is_super_puper_relama');
$criteria->params['is_super_puper_relama'] = '1234';
```